# MarkLogic REST interface to send data to Qlik Sense

Tags: rest, marklogic, qliksense

I need to present ~10 million XML documents to Qlik Sense using MarkLogic REST interface with the intention of analyzing raw data on Qlik.

I'm unable to send that bulk data using simple `cts:search`.

A template view with SQL call like below is not helping as it is not recognized at Qlik Sense.

```
xdmp:to-json(xdmp:sql('select * from SC1.V1'))
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

I understand it is not usual to load such huge data to Qlik, but what limitations should I consider?

Comment: Would QLik allow loading data in small batches, say about 100 to 500 docs per call?

Comment: Looks so. I wonder how to integrate that option. They allow pagination which looks for NextURL/NextPage/Offset etc

Comment: You can also explore scheduler for that which will run after few minute and call your query to send limitted data to Qlik.

Answer (score 2):

You are unlikely to be able transfer that volume of data into or out of ANY system in a single 'transaction' (or request ). And if you could you wouldn't want to because when it fails, it's likely to fail forever as you have to start all over.

You should 'batch' up the documents into manageable chunks .. 100MB or '1 minute' is a reasonable high upper bound -- as size and time increase the probability of problems goes up (way up) due to timeouts, memory, temp space, internet and network transient problems etc.

A simple strategy that often works well is to first produce a 'list' of what to extract (document uris, primary keys ..), save that, and then work your way through the list in batches - retrying as needed.  Depending on the destination and local storage etc.  you can either combine the lot to send on to the recipient, or generally better, send the target data in batches as well.

This approach has good transactional characteristics ... you effectively 'freeze' the set of data when you make the list, but can take your time collecting and sending it.  Depending -- you may be able to do so in parallel.

Comment: Thanks Daldei, Mads. That makes sense. 
I was researching on how can I send the data in batches and found that Qlik accepts something called _Pagination_ which can read NextURL/NextPage/Offset etc. 
Also, I see MarkLogic search:search has an option called `<page-length>`..
I am still trying to get these two work together. If you could share any sample that would be helpful.